# Can't correctly use fetch to PUT file on S3

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, filereader, fetch-api

Using a pre-signed URL I am trying to PUT an object (an image) in my AWS S3 bucket using JavaScript's `fetch`.

Below is the snippet of code I'm using, triggered by a change event on a file upload input.

```
// The event here is from a change
// trigger on the file input
const target = event.target
const file = target.files[0]
const reader = new FileReader()

reader.onload = (event) => {
  fetch(PRESIGNED_S3_URL, {
    method: 'put',
    body: event.target.result,
    headers: new Headers({
      'Content-Type': file.type
    }),
  }).then((response) => {
    response.json().then((data) => {
      // Success
    })
  })
}

// Read the selected file
reader.readAsText(file)
```

This does indeed upload the file, setting its name and filetype correctly, but when I try to view the file it is corrupt.

I am stuck on what I am doing incorrectly to read and upload the file contents. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Should the body be `target.files[0]`?

Comment: @Alan Negative - `event.target` at that point is the event of `FileReader`, which only produces `result` (which is the contents of the read file)

Comment: Which browser are you using? Are you using any libraries for this purpose? Usually javascript behaves differently on different browsers. The way to avoid that is to use some javascript framework such as angularJs or jQuery. You may get the correct result if you do the same thing through another javascript method, object or framework.

Comment: Did you check that the entire chain uses the same encoding (f.ex. utf-8) since you're dealing with text?

Comment: What's the content of the corrupt file? What happens when you look at the actual source.

Answer (score -1):

To upload an image, you need to set content handling to CONVERT_TO_BINARY.